# how to store javascript object as custom class

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, vue.js, nedb

I had a custom class, that defined in Javascript. I created an object based on the class and stored inside JSON database. When I retrieved the object, the prototype becomes object constructor, instead of custom class. I changed it by assign a custom class prototype to the object prototype.

**Problem**

> But inside the object has other key and values/object, each key has its custom class prototype too, but didn't replace it in nested level.

**Code**

```
let client = new CustomClient(); 
neDB.insert(client, (err, record) => {
  record.__proto__ = CustomClient.prototype;

  console.log('Custom client record', record);      
  this.ADD_DEVICE_SETTING(record)
})
```

**Custom client record**

```
{
   __proto__: CustomClient constructor
   object1: {
     __proto__: Object constructor
   },
   object2: {
     __proto__: Object constructor
   }
}
```

**Expected**

```
{
   __proto__: CustomClient constructor
   object1: {
     __proto__: CustomObject1 constructor
   },
   object2: {
     __proto__: CustomObject2 constructor
   }
}
```

**Question**

How do I replace all at once without assign one by one?

Comment: You can't. You have to serialize that.

Comment: @MarkusZeller JSON `stringify` and `parse` ?